# Check if document is read by current user

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, word

Hi Is there any way to know whether current user has read the word document in sharepoint online document library? I want to make sure that the user reads policy docs and tick the checkbox at the end that he agrees

Answer (score 2):

You could set things up in the Audit Setting http://SiteCollectionURL/_layouts/15/AuditSettings.aspx where you can select Open Document among other things.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quickie. I forgot to mention this is for sharepoint online site. Audit settings are not available there.

Comment: @SubbuVenkat Thanks for the heads up. I guess the fifth option (Opening...) will be available soon, because all other are.

Comment: @SubbuVenkat  - For SharePoint Online, the Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties event is not available. Check this link - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-A9920C97-38C0-44F2-8BCB-4CF1E2AE22D2